# How To Copy Cells And Paste Them As Values Using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Good day. I hope all is well.

Thank you Tanaike for helping me earlier.

**Problem:** I want to copy Cells C3:D6 (it contains formula) and paste them as Values in Cells C3:D6 (same cells). I am using the code below (specifically line/row 5) but it does not work.

```
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const row = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  sheet.getRange("C2:D2").copyTo(sheet.getRange(`C3:D` + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  sheet.getRange("C3:D3").copyTo(sheet.getRange(`C3:D` + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Is your expected result the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("C3:D6");
  range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true }); // or range.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); or range.setValues(range.getValues());
}
```

If you want to use the row number of `const row = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()`, how about the following modification?

```js
function foo() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const row = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  const range = sheet.getRange("C3:D" + row);
  range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true }); // or range.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); or range.setValues(range.getValues());
}
```

When this script is run, the values are copied from "C3:F6" to "C3:F6".

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)